# unexpected answers in multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my code that sum variable 'res' by one 4*10^7 time using 4 threads:

```
class MathSin extends Thread {

    public double a;

    public MathSin(int degree) {
        a = degree;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(10., 7); i++)
            MathThreads.res++;

    }
}

class MathThreads {
    public static double res = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MathSin st = new MathSin(8);
        MathSin ct = new MathSin(8);
        MathSin tt = new MathSin(8);
        MathSin qt = new MathSin(8);
        st.start();
        ct.start();
        tt.start();
        qt.start();
        try { // wait for completion of all thread and then sum
            st.join();
            ct.join(); // wait for completion of MathCos object
            tt.join();
            qt.join();
            System.out.println(res);
        } catch (InterruptedException IntExp) {
        }
    }
}
```

and these are some of answers :

```
1.8499044E7

2.3446789E7
.
.
.
```

I expected get 3.0E7 but get another different answers.

how can fix this problem?

Comment: If no other threads "check" `res` before modifying it, you coulf make it volatile so other threads see the new value when a thread updates it. Otherwise, you need atomicy to ensure you have a "happens-before" relationship with checking the variables and setting the variable. Look into how to handle variables across multiple threads

Comment: You need atomicity, `double` cannot be updated in one round, so `volatile` is not enough. (Though it will be probably slower with the threads than without.)

Comment: @GáborBakos What do you mean by "*double cannot be updated in one round*"? I've never heard that before, but I haven't dug into concurrency enough to stumble across that problem. Is this in the JLS or some other official documentation?

Comment: @VinceEmigh http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7 So you were right. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What is the problem?

You are observing race conditions while updating the `static` variable `res`.

```
MathThreads.res++
```

is equivalent to:

```
double tmp = MathThreads.res;
MathThreads.res = tmp + 1;
```

Now what happened if two threads reads *at the same time* a value for `tmp`, and both update `res` with `tmp + 1`? Well, one increment has simply been forgotten: `res` ends being `tmp + 1` instead of being `tmp + 1 + 1`!

So with 4 threads updating `res` concurrently, you simply end up with an undefined behavior : it is impossible to predict the final value of `res` because of those race conditions. Two executions of the same code will give you different answers.

### How to solve this issue?

To make your code thread-safe, you need to use a thread-safe structure for `res`: a structure that can be concurrently updated and accessed.

In your case, an `AtomicLong` seems the perfect choice:

```
public static AtomicLong res = new AtomicLong(0);
```

And in the run method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(10., 7); i++) {
    MathThreads.res.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: this code only sum res by one. if i want to sum res by another number or divide it by a number or ... , how can do?

Comment: @ggtty use `addAndGet(n)` to add or subtract.  Division is an unlikely operation but you can use use a loop with compareAndSet for an arbitrary operation.